Azure pipeline for multistage
  - stage: PublishStage
    dependsOn: [PreStage, CheckTestProjects, TestStage]
    condition: |
      and(
        succeeded(),
        or(
          eq(dependencies.TestStage.result, 'succeeded'),
          eq(dependencies.TestStage.result, 'skipped')
        )
      )
    jobs:
      - template: PublishNuget_jobs_template.yml@templates
        parameters:
          buildConfiguration: '${{ variables.buildConfiguration }}'
          feed: '${{ variables.feed }}'

The pipeline always skips the publish stage.
What i would like to achieve:

If the TestStage was skipped (for eg.: testproject did not exist) publish stage should run
If TestStage was successfull it needs to run
If TestStage failed don't run publish

Any Idea?
I have tried:
- stage: PublishStage
  dependsOn: [PreStage, CheckTestProjects, TestStage]
  condition: and(not(failed('TestStage')))
  jobs:
    - template: PublishNuget_jobs_template.yml@templates
      parameters:
        buildConfiguration: '${{ variables.buildConfiguration }}'
        feed: '${{ variables.feed }}'


Hi SzAdam88, can you please let me know if condition: in(dependencies.TestStage.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped') can help you solve the issue?


What I would like to achieve:

If the TestStage was skipped (for eg.: testproject did not exist) publish  stage should run
If TestStage was successfull it needs to run
If TestStage failed don't run publish


You can use the condition like the following sample to achieve what you need. For more details, please refer Stage to stage dependencies
- stage: PublishStage
  dependsOn: [PreStage, CheckTestProjects, TestStage]
  condition: in(dependencies.TestStage.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped')
  jobs:
    - template: PublishNuget_jobs_template.yml@templates
      parameters:
        buildConfiguration: '${{ variables.buildConfiguration }}'
        feed: '${{ variables.feed }}'

My test result:

